# Minimum number of inequalities characterizing a point

Tags: geometry, inequality, vector-spaces

Suppose I have a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$. My question is, what the minimum number of inequalities $\phi_i^\top x \geq y_i$ is that is needed to uniquely characterize $x$, where $\phi_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $y_i \in \mathbb{R}$. When I try it out in 2-dimensions, it seems that $d+1$ inequalities are required.

How can I show that there always exist such $d+1$ inequalities that characterize a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$? A reference to a book would also be very welcomed, as I couldn't find such a statement so far.

Comment: When you write $\phi_i^T x \ge 0$, do you mean that you only allow homogenious inequalities? If so, it is impossible to characterize anything besides $x = 0$. For $x= 0$ one can write $d$ inequalities saying that each coordinate is non-negative, and one more inequality saying that the sum of coordinates is non-positive.

Comment: @SashaKozachinskiy Oh, you're right. I will change it so that it can also be inhomogenious inequalities.